# Define URL in PHP File throw error in featured PHP Version

Tags: php

I have a file called `web.php` inside that file I store code for define `base URL address, assets folder...`.  File have next code:

```
<?php
    define('BASE', 'https://example.com/');
    define('ASSETS', BASE . 'assets/');
?>
```

So if we call function from above `<?php echo BASE; ?>home.php` i get error that says, check above.

All works fine but get an error that says,  `` you need to change `BASE` it will throw an error in featured PHP Versions ``. I try to define different names, but same error. Can someone explain to me, how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to repeat your Error

And as i see there no Errors at all

My PHP version is 7.4.3

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('BASE', 'https://example.com/');
define('ASSETS', BASE . 'assets/');

echo BASE;

echo "No errors";
```

Is it really php throw or may by it comes from your Framework?

Comment: I will update my question because I think that you even don't know what is code for.

Comment: @Jerry, added `echo BASE;` to my code and still no errors.
Could you please provide all files?

Comment: You need to create file ```file-1.php``` store the above code i the write-in question. And in second file call it ```include 'file-1.php';``` and call the code ```<a href="<?php echo BASE; ?>home">Go to page<a/>```. And upload it on your website, so you will get ```error-log``` file with that message. If I get that message, that message is because I use PHP 8 or ```latest PHP Version```. Please, someone who have experience, answer me.

Comment: Ok.
I installed php 8 on my server

And try to repeat your code.
And it works perfect, still no errors at all

Comment: Okay, if you have your HOST place where you can upload website files. Upload 2 files you created and then open the website, open your host root/directory and you will see a file called ```error-log``` and when you open it you will see the error. It not error like you enter wrong password, this error says that we need to change that because on featured versions of PHP will throw an error.